# Threejs coordinates of a destination, from an origin, a direction and distance

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

Following the building of a simple Lidar 3D scanner, I now plan to build a 3D representation with Threejs.

As the generated data is a simple list of distance, horizontal angle, and vertical angle, I try to figure out how to calculate the coordinates  [x,y,z] of the points with these data...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Take a look a the [`.setFromSphericalCoords()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3.setFromSphericalCoords) method of `THREE.Vector3()`

Comment: Yeah that's it, you rocks, thank you :)